# how to use rownumber over partition in ODI MAPPING

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

My requirement is to get the recent record grouped by columns c1,c2.I have 50 columns in my source, using query i can apply rownumber() over partition by c1,c2 order by record_time desc, and pick the record where rownumber=1. In short, my oracle query would be:

select c1,c2,....,c50
from (select c1,c2,....,c50,
row_number() over (partition by c1,c2 order by record_time desc ) rn
from table)
where rn = 1;

How can I achieve this using ODI mapping? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: One option would be creating a view with the above query, which contains row_number() , and using it within ODI analytic function.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the version of ODI you are using, assuming you are using ODI 11g. You can create a yellow interface and create a column for rownum with expression as below
row_number() over (partition by c1,c2 order by record_time desc)

Now use this yellow interface as source in your interface and apply filter on rownum column as below
rownum = 1

While using this you will have to make sure your KM is not adding group by function, else it'll end up in error.